# How to retrieve saved UIImageViews from documents folder in Swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview

Im creating this app that takes a picture and displays it in a UIImageView. When I press on the save button it should save the images to the document directory. Then I want to be able to retrieve these images in my collection view. I have the code below that saves the images but how would I retrieve it in my collection view? Thanks!

**First View Controller - save images**

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage) -> String {

let imageData = NSData(data: image.pngData()!)
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,  FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
 let docs = paths[0] as NSString
 let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString + ".png"
 let fullPath = docs.appendingPathComponent(uuid)
 _ = imageData.write(toFile: fullPath, atomically: true)
return uuid
 }



@IBAction func didPressSaveButton(_ sender: Any) {
                      

 for _ in self.images {
   _ = self.saveImage(image: self.imageView.image!)
      }

}
```

**Second View Controller- retrieve images**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as!
    MyPicturesCollectionViewCell
           
    

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve it like this

```
func loadImageFromDocumentDirectory(nameOfImage : String) -> UIImage? {

    let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true)
    if let dirPath = paths.first{
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(nameOfImage)
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
            return image

        } else {
            print("image not found")

            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And for saving

```
func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage , imageName: String) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileName = imageName // name of the image to be saved
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1),
        !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("file saved")
        } catch {
            print("error saving file:", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting an error on this line `self.saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: self.imageView.image!, imageName: "images")` It says Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: dont force unwrap `self.imageView.image!`

Comment: call it with `if let` to check either your imageview have image ...

Comment: like `if let image = self.imageView.image {self.saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: image, imageName: "images") } else {print("image not found")}`

Comment: Thanks for that but its not saving in the document directory for some reason. It prints out the `image not found` when saving and retrieving the image.

Comment: its because your image is nil ... which you are trying to save .... make sure your imageview have image